# Compare boost intrusive_ptr with different const-ness

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, constants, smart-pointers

I would like to compare `boost::intrusive_ptr` instances with different const-ness of underlying type, but unfortunately it [doesn't work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4WSSJjlIjIhOtgpU) from the box if you uncomment the line:

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <memory>

struct S {};

void intrusive_ptr_release(const S*){}

int main() { 

    boost::intrusive_ptr<const S> boost_const_ptr;
    boost::intrusive_ptr<S> boost_ptr;
    // if(boost_const_ptr < boost_ptr) {} // <------ here
    
    const S* s_const_ptr;
    S* s_ptr;
    if(s_const_ptr < s_ptr) {}

    std::unique_ptr<const S> u_const_ptr;
    std::unique_ptr<S> u_ptr;
    if(u_const_ptr < u_ptr) {}
}
```

The error will be:

```
no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'boost::intrusive_ptr<const S>' and 'boost::intrusive_ptr<S>')
```

I can compare raw pointers, or even `std::unique_ptr`s, but not `boost::intrusive_ptr`. Is there a reason for it, or just an oversight?

Comment: I estimate that it is 99% likely to be an oversight.  To be sure, you should ask Peter Dimov in particular, the author of Boost intrusive_ptr.  Or Greg Colvin, Beman Dawes, and/or Glen Fernandes if Peter is unavailable.

Comment: @Turtlefight That commit only updates documentation. Your godbolt snippet doesn't compile if you uncomment the comparison. I don't think it ever worked, and given that comparison for (in)equality for different pointee types is supported, this is most likely an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason is that equivalent semantics to `shared_ptr` < would be impossible in general. Other smart pointer types don't have to deal with the possibility of heterogenous comparison<sup>1</sup>, but `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `intrusive_ptr` do.

> ```
> template<class T, class U>
> bool operator<(shared_ptr<T> const & a, shared_ptr<U> const & b) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> An unspecified value such that
>
> - `operator<` is a strict weak ordering as described in section [lib.alg.sorting] of the C++ standard;
> - under the equivalence relation defined by `operator<`, `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`, two shared_ptr instances are equivalent if and only if they
>   share ownership or are both empty.

`shared_ptr` is able to do that by comparing addresses of the ref count. `intrusive_ptr` can't do that, because it doesn't have pointer access to the ref count.

1. E.g. when you compare a `shared_ptr<Base>` to a `shared_ptr<Derived>` they might share ownership of the same object, which is impossible for `unique_ptr<Base>` and `unique_ptr<Derived>`.

Answer (score 0):

You might add an overload for your types to be found via ADL:

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <memory>

namespace MyStuff {
    struct S {};

    void intrusive_ptr_release(S const*) {}

    template <typename T, typename U, typename V = std::remove_cv_t<T>>
        requires std::is_same_v<V, std::remove_cv_t<U>>
    constexpr bool operator<(boost::intrusive_ptr<T> const& a, boost::intrusive_ptr<U> const& b) {
        return std::less<V const*>{}(a.get(), b.get());
    }
} // namespace MyStuff
```

Note how the ADL overload takes precedence so we don't need to SFINAE constrain for the case `T === U` to avoid creating ambiguous overloads:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/903126165d4a0e93)**

```
int main() {
    using MyStuff::S;
    {
        boost::intrusive_ptr<S const> cp;
        boost::intrusive_ptr<S>       p;

        if (cp < p) { }
        if (cp < cp) { }
        if (p < p) { }
    }

    {
        S const* cp = nullptr;
        S*       p  = nullptr;

        if (cp < p) { }
        if (cp < cp) { }
        if (p < p) { }
    }

    {
        std::unique_ptr<S const> cp;
        std::unique_ptr<S>       p;

        if (cp < p) { }
        if (cp < cp) { }
        if (p < p) { }
    }
}
```

### BONUS

A [c++17 version](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b91b2889091d9778):

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V = std::remove_cv_t<T>>
constexpr auto operator<(boost::intrusive_ptr<T> const& a, boost::intrusive_ptr<U> const& b)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<V, std::remove_cv_t<U>>, bool> {
    return std::less<V const*>{}(a.get(), b.get());
}
```

Pure [c++11 version](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26c9748c876ab76d):

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V = typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>
constexpr auto operator<(boost::intrusive_ptr<T> const& a, boost::intrusive_ptr<U> const& b)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<V, typename std::remove_cv<U>::type>::value, bool>::type {
    return std::less<V const*>{}(a.get(), b.get());
}
```